Using NavigationStack with NSPopover in status bar item
I have created a status bar item that shows a popover view when it is clicked
import SwiftUI

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var popover: NSPopover!
    
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: 125)
    
    @IBOutlet weak var menu: NSMenu!
        override internal func awakeFromNib() {
            statusItem.button?.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
    }
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let popover = NSPopover()
        self.popover = popover
        
        popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: NavigatorView() )
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
         if let button = statusItem.button {
              if self.popover.isShown {
                   self.popover.performClose(sender) } else {
                       self.popover.behavior = NSPopover.Behavior.transient
                       self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
                       
    } } } }

Within this popover I would like to use a navigation stack:
import SwiftUI

struct NavigatorView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Test", destination: EmptyView())
            }
        }
    }
}

This seems to work.

However, if there is a navigation to a new view, there is no button to return to the original navigation stack.

From all the tutorials I have seen, there should be text in the top left corner that brings me back to the navigation stack. However, I am unsure if I have failed follow the tutorial in the correct manner or whether there is an issue when navigation stacks are used with popovers.
In either case, I would like the Empty View that is clicked from the navigation stack to include some link to go back to the navigation stack like in this example from https://www.swiftyplace.com/blog/better-navigation-in-swiftui-with-navigation-stack.


ever find a solution? this is so absurd lol

You should rely on macOS tutorials when you expect it to work on macOS. Anyways, I think it can't work (prove me wrong ...), the popover doesn't have a title bar so NavigationStack does not know where to put the Back button.
